# In Next.js 13 using App Router, why can't I export dynamic routes with "use client"?

Tags: next.js

I'm using Next.js 13 with the App Router and have a page that uses dynamic routes. It works well when I run the server locally (`localhost:3000//tickets/2`, for instance), but fails with prerender errors when I try to export a static site via `npm run build`.

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/tickets/[id]". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
```

Some notes:

- I have `"use client"` at the top of the page. As I understand it, that's required if I'm using the `useState` hook.
- If I remove `"use client"` and all the state management stuff, `npm run build` exports everything without a hitch (i.e. Nextjs builds a static page for each ticket id like /tickets/1, tickets/2, etc.).

I'm not sure why I'm unable to export a static site with `useState` on a page accessed via a dynamic route. Here's my setup, with just the relevant parts:

**next.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  output: "export",
  images: {
    unoptimized: true,
  }
};;
```

**app/tickets/[id]/page.js**

```js
"use client";

import { useState } from "react";
import Select from "components/Select";

const TICKETS = [
  { id: 0, status: "open" },
  { id: 1, status: "open" },
  { id: 2, status: "resolved" },
  { id: 3, status: "canceled" },
  { id: 4, status: "resolved" }
]

// Dynamic routes; create a page for each ticket ID
export async function generateStaticParams() {
  return TICKETS.map((ticket) => ({
    id: `${ticket.id}`,
  }));
}

export default function Ticket({ params }) {
  const { id } = params;
  const ticket = TICKETS[id];
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(ticket.status);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{ticket.id}</h1>
      <Select
        onValueChange={(e) => {
          setStatus(e);
        }}
        value={status}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/46735 Apparently `generateStaticParams` only supported in server component. Any workaround?

Comment: OK, that definitely sounds like the problem—thanks for the heads up! I'm just trying to statically generate a site with dynamic routes, but I also need to do this client-side so I can use `useState`. In Next.js 12, I could use `getStaticPaths`, but the docs say "In the app directory, getStaticPaths is replaced with generateStaticParams." I wonder if this is not possible in v13?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to move client component out of `page.js` and import it instead.

`generateStaticParams` is not supported in client component, but importing client component in server component is ok.

**Ticket.js**

```js
"use client"

// ..imports

export default function Ticket({ params }) {
  const { id } = params;
  const ticket = TICKETS[id];
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(ticket.status);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{ticket.id}</h1>
      <Select
        onValueChange={(e) => {
          setStatus(e);
        }}
        value={status}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Page.js**

```js
import Ticket from "./ticket";

// ...

// Dynamic routes; create a page for each ticket ID
export async function generateStaticParams() {
  return TICKETS.map((ticket) => ({
    id: `${ticket.id}`,
  }));
}

export default function Page({ params }) {
  return <Ticket id={params.id}>;
}
```

#### Reference

- https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns#interleaving-server-and-client-components

Comment: Great answer, I did not even know this was possible. Which is pretty surprising and amazing.

Comment: Out of a whole morning trying to create a quick NextJs site, first time using the App Router method, this post has explained more about how to "make it work" than any other site.